# what's the difference between interface pointer and interface value in golang

Tags: go, interface, type-conversion

when `Node` is a struct type, it can't compiled.

but when `Node` is a interface type it's ok.

why?

```golang
type Node interface {
}
// test1's parameter are pointer
func test1(b *Node) {
    test2(b)
}
// test2's parameter are not pointer
func test2(c Node) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at some variations on the declaration of `Node`:

Example 1:

```
type Node interface {
}
```

The code compiles because all types satisfy the empty interface.

Example 2:

```
type Node interface {
   AnyMethod()
}
```

The compiler reports the following error:

> cannot use b (type *Node) as type Node in argument to test2: *Node is pointer to interface, not interface

The compilation fails because a `*Node` does not have the method `AnyMethod`.

Example 3:

```
type Node struct {
}
```

The compiler reports the following error:

> cannot use b (type *Node) as type Node in argument to test2

The compilation fails because `*Node` and `Node` are different types.

One fix for the compilation error is dereference the pointer:

```
func test1(b *Node) {
    test2(*b)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in your title: an interface pointer is a pointer to an interface value.  However, an interface pointer is not that useful as an interface is a reference type already.

As to why your code does not compile when `Node` is a struct, you are trying to pass a pointer to a function that takes a value.  You should do this instead:

```
func test1(b *Node) {
    test2(*b)
}
```

But when `Node` is an empty interface the parameter of `test2()` is of type `interface{}` also called the empty interface.  Any type (including `b` which is a pointer) will be implicitly converted to an empty interface.  Hence **passing anything to `test2()` will compile** when its parameter is of type `interface{}`.

Comment: I found that [Method_sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) . is there something like java's upcasting in go? for example casting `*Node` to `Node?`

Comment: Yes there is.  (I'll tell you if you accept my answer :)