# What should I do instead of a pointer to an interface?

Tags: go, pointers, interface

I am creating a datastructure for what is essentially a block diagram/ flowchart

I have

```
type Block interface {
    next Block
}
```

Then I have various types of blocks ex:

```
type PassBlock struct{
    next Block
}
func (block *PassBlock) next() Block {
    return block.next
}
```

I have an array containing a bunch of blocks. I will use the `start()` method to find the first block

```
func (barr blockArrStruct) StartBlock() (Block) {
    return &barr.arr[0]
}
```

However here I am getting a compiler error because I cannot do `&barr.arr[0]` since this is a pointer to an interface.

I was wondering what method I should use to accomplish my task.

Obviously I could simply use array indices and not even worry about any of this.

But if there was a pointer method available then I feel like that could have its advantages, IE not having to worry about validating array indices, etc. I could depend on the compiler to manage safety for me. Every pointer to a block would necessarily point to a block.

Comment: Simply do `return barr.arr[0]`

Comment: I think returning `barr.arr[0]` is enough. it's because it is `Block` (interface). Interface behave like a pointer 
 or a reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76734534/what-should-i-do-instead-of-a-pointer-to-an-interface https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146693/whats-the-difference-between-interface-pointer-and-interface-value-in-golang